# The Burgers equation $u_y + u u_x = 1$ with $u=0$ on the parabola $y^2=2x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

> For the PDE $u_y + u u_x = 1$, sketch a plot of $\Gamma$ and a few representative curves, including the envelope curve. Conditions: $u=0$ on the curve $y^2=2x$, and $y,x>0$. Express $u$ as a function of $x,y$.

I'm new to PDE's and very lost. I saw similar problems on here, but not identical. I'm pretty sure I have to use the Method of Characteristics. But I'm not sure how you find the curve Gamma, or parameterize everything.

Answer (score 0):

Analytic solving of the PDE :
$$u_y + uu_x=1$$
Thanks to the method of characteristics :
$$\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dx}{u}=-\frac{du}{1}$$
On the characteristic curves : 
  \begin{cases}
    dx+udu=0\:\:\rightarrow\:\: 2x+u^2=c_1\\
    dy+du=0\:\:\rightarrow\:\: y+u=c_2\\
  \end{cases}
The general solution can be expressed on the form : 
$$\Phi\left(2x+u^2\:,\: y+u\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any derivable function of two variables.

This is equivalent of the implicit equation:
$$2x+u^2=F(y+u)$$
where $F$ is any derivable function.

The boundary condition $u=0$ on $2x=y^2$ implies $2x=y^2=F(y)$ Hense $F$ is the square function.
$$2x+u^2=(y+u)^2$$
$$u(x,y)=\frac{2x-y^2}{2y}$$